# How to check special character support with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, special-characters, symbols

How can I check if a special character is available in the user's computer?

For example: ♥ ♦ ♣ ♠ ♪ ♫ ¶

If the user's browser doesn't support one of them, then a rectangle () will appear instead of the symbol.

Comment: You check for specific fonts. The computer couldn't care less if a font doesn't have a particular glyph defined.

Comment: Not sure, but I think this has more to do with the charset that's in the HTTP header rather than the browser or OS.

Comment: If you want to check for specific fonts, here's a technique you can try:  http://lucassmith.name/2009/05/test-if-a-font-is-installed-via-javascript.html.  Other than that, I don't think there's an easy way other than viewing the user's screen to see if the character shows correctly.

Comment: I've got an idea. I check, if the symbol, and the rectangle the same sizes have.

Comment: @DannyFox: And if I use something like LiberationSans instead of Arial I get different sizes but still have the right character...

Comment: You could make sure you wrap the special characters in a special span with a class that makes it Arial; normalizing it to fit your font height/width and styles. If you use ems / relative units this should be fairly easy to do for all areas and cases with one class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m afraid there’s no way to test it, and there’s the added complexity that even if a character is available, browsers (especially IE) may fail to render it.

On the other hand, the information would not be particularly useful, except perhaps in the sense that you could dynamically change the character to an image if it can’t be rendered as a character.

A better approach to having your characters rendered properly is to write your style sheets so that they select suitable fonts. This also addresses the problem that a character might be displayed using a font that does not suit the overall design, such as the basic copytext font.

For example, if you need the characters ♥ ♦ ♣ ♠ ♪ ♫ ¶, select a font that contains them and all the other characters you need. This would probably boil down just to

```
body { font-family: Arial, sans-serif; }
```

Comment: It doesn't work, because the symbols aren't part of the font-families.

Comment: @Danny Fox, please check http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/test/symbols.html8
If it displays OK, as I suspect, then the problem is not in fonts at all but probably somewhere else, e.g. in character encoding. In that case, even common non-Ascii letters like “é” (when entered directly) probably won’t work, and this can hardly be a font problem. You could also verify this by testing what happens when you enter the characters as references: `&#x2665; &#x2666; &#x2663; &#x2660; &#x266A; &#x266B; &#x00B6;`.

Comment: I tested it on some device, but if the symbol is not supported, then the reference also doesn't work.

Comment: @Danny Fox, which device? Did *all* the symbols fail? Testing on Android, I was surprised at seeing that the beamed eighth notes ♫ is not present in its fonts, but then again, what can you do?

Comment: if it's not supported, I replace it with png image

Answer (score -1):

a different solution can be using google's webfonts

http://www.google.com/webfonts

if you see a character, every other computer [with a recent browser] will see it